# Visual Studio 2015 - how to run: vs2015.1 rc.exe /override feed url <Path to feed.xml>

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015

It happened that I cancelled an update when updating Visual Studio 2015 Community,

it cannot load the original solution I have had,

It gave such error:
Invalid entries passed to /FilterFeatureSelectionTree

then I searched on [MSDN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3039361) said to run:

VS2015.1 RC.exe /overridefeeduri

But it is said "Syntax incorrect in command"

Does anyone know how to run the above command successfully?

Answer (score 3):

`VS2015.1 RC.exe` refers to the Visual Studio 2015 installer executable. So for example, if you saved the installer as `C:\vs_community_ENU.exe` and you want to use the English `feed.xml`, the command line would be:

```
C:\vs_community_ENU.exe /overridefeeduri "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=564093&clcid=0x409"
```

Note that the URL needs to be in quotes if executing from the command-line, otherwise the command-line interpreter might misinterpret the `&` in the URL and think that you're trying to issue multiple commands.

Comment: Hi Jason, so I supposed I am to run:
VS2015.1 RC.exe /overridefeeduri "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=564093&clcid=0x409"
but in which directory I should run that? Because I couldn't find vs2015.1 and rc.exe
instead, I downloaded vs2015.1 and took a rc.exe from windows sdk, put in a random temp folder to run it, but seemed unsuccessful

Comment: Jason, Why did you remove the string RC.exe from the command?  This is tripping me up too.

Comment: Think of "VS2015.1 RC.exe" as a placeholder string. You need to replace the entire "VS2015.1 RC.exe" part of the command line with the installer executable file name.

Comment: What if I am updating some feature in Visual Studio? How will know its executable. Now I have already closed the window. It took so much time to give this error message. I dont want to run it again. Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to solve this is to download VS 2015 setup here: https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs

then run the installer, choose "Modify" and select features you want install.

it did work for me as I wasn't able to install Python Tools from Visual Studio, but running the installer di solve the issue.

According log from failling installer, xml feed was alright, so previous answer cannot help.

**Edit:** I think the bug appears once you run the Web Platform installer, and if you cannot install it with VS installer, you should use Web Platform Installer instead

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to know the path URI for the feed.  MSDN says the syntax is

> `VS2015.1 RC.exe /overridefeeduri <Path to feed.xml>`

You left off the last argument. The english feed URI is `http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=564093&clcid=0x409`. The page you linked contains the URIs for other languages if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I have the same issue and have tried to paste the command (with all the arguments :) into windows command line (Win + R) and also into Windows PowerShell. In both cases the error appears that VS2015.1 cannot be found or is not recognized. I guess I am not pasting the command into the right place or my path is broken. I would appreciate any comments or suggestions regarding this. Thanks.

Comment: When trying to run the command I get: "'VS2015.1' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file." Is there a path we need to switch to before running the command?

Comment: I actually did add with the url, but just like what Sergei and Ovidiu said, I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't also able to install Python Tools from Visual Studio. Then I resolved this issue by trying multiple trial and error steps.

Trial 1:
 I researched to find out the installer that installed the MSVS2015 in my Machine.As it was my office PC the installation was pushed out by the IT. The installer I found was at this directory

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\VS_SDKV1\en\0\vs****.exe

then I applied the following command

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudioSecondaryInstaller\14.0\installers\VS_SDKV1\en\0\vs****.exe /overridefeeduri feed.xml
```

After doing this My VS became unresponsive. I could not start it from the start menu.I thought I have by any chance damaged my Installation.Now I moved forward to step 2.

Trial 2:

- go to Control Panel>Programs and features>select [Microsoft Visual studio 2015]>rightclick>[change]
- On the screeen that appears on the window hit "Repair"
- After the repair is complete. I repeated step a and this time I hit "modify" button. selected the "Python tools for Visual studio" and moved forward with "install/next" etc.

It worked out.I think only step 2 is good enough to set things right.I am not sure if Trial 1 did any good or not.

Thanks.